# Method not calling of RestController of Spring mvc4

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I wrote Code for restful api but method is not calling,
getting error "Context Root Not Found".

I am using liberty profile

Here is a my code
Controller

```
@RestController
public class demoAPIController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/restcall", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<String> GetParseResume() {
        return new ResponseEntity("hello", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

WebAppInitializer

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("*.html");
        dispatcher.addMapping("*.pdf");
        dispatcher.addMapping("*.json");
    }

    private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext()
    {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();    
        context.register(WebConfig.class);
        return context;
    }

}
```

here WebConfig.java

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.demo")
    public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
        @Bean
        public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
            InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolve = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            viewResolve.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
            viewResolve.setSuffix(".jsp");
            return viewResolve;
        }
    }
```

Error showing in Spring tool suite while start liberty server

```
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0002E: An exception occurred while starting the application demo1. The exception message was: java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.ibm.wsspi.adaptable.module.UnableToAdaptException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
```

Comment: Seems that a jar is corrupted. Would consider deleting the related jars in the maven cache and reload them.

Comment: @mh-dev I tried right click on project and go to Maven -> Update Project. but still not working.. How to delete maven cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems some backend side file was corrupted.

I did right click on pom.xml -> maven -> clean and install again.

Error resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Possible cause would be your liberty does not support servlet 3.0+. So you should do some tweaking according to spring recommends

> Spring Boot uses Servlet 3.0 APIs to initialize the ServletContext
>   (register Servlets etc.) so you can’t use the same application out of
>   the box in a Servlet 2.5 container. It is however possible to run a Spring Boot application on an older container with some special tools. If you include org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-legacy as a dependency (maintained separately to the core of Spring Boot and currently available at 1.0.2.RELEASE), all you should need to do is create a web.xml and declare a context listener to create the application context and your filters and servlets.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-servlet-2-5

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>demo.Application</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.SpringBootContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>metricFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>metricFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: When I tried first time at that time it was working so I am sure it is not issue with version.. Suddenly it was showing such type of error. May be something corrupted or some changes made in backed side..

Comment: yep. then you can try by cleaing and make new build

Comment: mvn clean install